# Application.properties for each environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create `application.properties` for each environment. By default, the existing one is `application.properties` when I try to add a new file having `.properties` as extension, the icon of the file is not the same as the `application.properties`. I get the icon of the `Ressource bundle`. 
This is how I create the new file:
Right click on my `ressources` package -> New -> File

Then for the its name I put `application_dev.properties`.

How can I get a `spring boot` properties file instead of a `Ressource bundle` one?

Comment: which IDE did you use?

Comment: @JoseMartinez Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the convention. Resource bundles use underscores. You want to use dashes.

- application-local.properties
- application-dev.properties
- application-staging.propertes

And then use `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` flag to switch and/or `@ActiveProfiles("dev")` to trigger which profile is used.

Comment: Thank you the files are created now correctly. For the flag how about spring.profiles.active= dev ? And should I always put as value the word after "-" ? For example if I want to use the application-local.properties have I to put spring.profiles.active= local?

Comment: If you want to use a profile other than the default `application.properties` you need to tell Spring which profile to use. So whatever comes after `application-` is what you use.

Comment: Also note that application.properties is still read and the chosen profile will simply add to and/or overwrite existing properties. So both will be used.

Comment: So if I use -Dspring.profiles.action=dev or  spring.profiles.active= dev it's the same thing. Is that what you mean?

Comment: HA, no. That's my bad. Typo. I've edited my answer. It should always be `active` not `action`. Sorry about that.

Comment: It's not a problem. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: You might want to include a link to the Spring Boot reference guide explaining the resource loading and naming scheme for property/yml files. Just for completeness of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option here is to just put the application.properties in the environment outside of the SpringBoot JAR.  That way the environmental specific options are configured in the environment not in the build so you do not have to do different builds for each environment.   It can be a big complexity and time saver.